# How do I dynamically take variables from previous plays in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

Example, I have 3 tasks, which are registered `ec21`, `ec22` and `ec23`.

`ec22` runs when `ec21` fails, and `ec23` runs when `ec22` fails.

Now, I have another task below it which is :

```
- name: Add new instance to host group
  add_host:
    hostname: "{{ item.private_ip }}"
    groupname: launched
  with_items: "{{ ec2x.instances }}"
```

where `ec2x`is any of the previous tasks.

So, how do I set `ec2x` here?  cause, **Any of my 3 tasks can run**. So, it can be `ec21` or `ec22` or `ec23`.  So, how do I dynamically write that in the adding task after them?

Answer (score 5):

It feels dirty, but I guess something like that would work:

```
- name: ec21
  [...]
  register: ec21_result

- set_fact: end_result= "{{ ec21_result }}"
  when: ec21_result|succeeded

- name: ec22
  [...]
  register: ec22_result
  when: ec21_result|failed

- set_fact: end_result= "{{ ec22_result }}"
  when: ec22_result|succeeded

- name: ec23
  [...]
  register: ec23_result
  when: ec22_result|failed

- set_fact: end_result= "{{ ec23_result }}"
  when: ec23_result|succeeded

- name: Add new instance to host group
  add_host:
    hostname: "{{ item.private_ip }}"
    groupname: launched
  with_items: "{{ end_result.instances }}"
```

Basically setting the `end_result` as soon as you succeed a play.

Comment: Seems to work.  But, this [small issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/ansible/comments/69xhkw/why_is_my_set_fact_play_running_even_when_the/?st=j2g3fluo&sh=7c840e20) is roadblocking the entire thing :D . Possible to know how to stop the failed `set_facts` tasks from setting empty values to it?

Comment: You mean that if ec22 is ok, and then ec23 fail, then the fact will be set to an empty value ?
What's your Ansible version ?